# Why SharePoint 2016 is not referring images from 16 hive folder?

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, 2016, hive

We migrated the SharePoint 2013 solutions to 2016.
But all images are deployed in 16 hive folder.In 15 hive folder images are not there but SharePoint site still referring the 15 hive folder path.

If i give the url   `ImageUrl="**/_layouts/16**/images/icon.png?` its not referring this path images are not displaying. If i give `ImageUrl="**/_layouts/15/**images/icon.png?` it was working and all images are displaying.

Why is this happening? which path should we refer? 16 hive folder or 15 hive folder?

Comment: check the answer here - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183693/why-are-image-files-in-16-hive-referred-through-layouts-15-on-a-sharepoint-2016