# SharePoint 2016 installation there is no 15 hive folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, hive

Recently i was installed the sharepoint 2016.Web application was created.But there is no 15 hive folder.But other sharepoint 2016 server having 14,15,16 hive folder.I was applying some css changes.But is not appear in that site.

Why that 15 hive folder is not there.Can you please anyone give me reason for this.

[image]
I refered this link
[enter link description here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27c290b7-a366-4174-9ca5-22c6d5b529e6/15-hive-is-missing-from-sharepoint-2016?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: Also check out the answer to this one: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183693/why-are-files-in-16-hive-referred-through-layouts-15-on-a-sharepoint-2016-serve

Comment: To create 15 hive folder, you must install SharePoint designer first.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the MSDN forum link once.

[15 Hive is missing from SharePoint 2016](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27c290b7-a366-4174-9ca5-22c6d5b529e6/15-hive-is-missing-from-sharepoint-2016?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Whether you use the customized solutions for SharePoint 2013 in the new SharePoint 2016 environment?

If so, install the solution in the 15 CompatibilityLevel.

Reference:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534(v=office.16).aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes we are migrating the VS 2013 solutions to sharepoint 2016.How we can install the solution in the 15 CompatibilityLevel.

Comment: install the solution in the 15 CompatibilityLevel.

Comment: C:\PS>Install-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp -GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel {14,15} check the Technet link once for more details

Comment: 15 hive folder was not there means is there any issues ?So many places we are referring 15 hive folder in code.For example /_LAYOUTS/15/1033/IMAGES/.

Answer (score 0):

A standard installation of SharePoint Server 2016 will only create a 14 folder and a 16 folder. There is no 15 folder in the hive (i.e. at ...\Web Server Extensions\15). The reason they did this was to not break compatibility with v15 sites.

Furthermore there's no compatibility level available in 2016 (yes the switch is there, but there's no point). All sites are v15 and there is no backwards compatibility with v14.5. This was for ease of migration.

This was essentially a feature for Microsoft and is why all sites must be in v15 compat mode prior to upgrading to 2016.

About standard installation means you were installed SharePoint 2016 directly , such as manually run the prerequest.exe, setup.exe and so on . not upgrade from 2013 .